# Inherits Interface in VB - Porting code from C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

So, I'm working with a library (Coderr, for anyone familiar with it), that's written in C#, and so are their examples. My project is of course in VB, and I'm a bit confused on implementing a template of their example classes.

An example of one of their existing classes is [here](https://github.com/coderrio/Coderr.Client.AspNet/blob/master/src/Coderr.Client.AspNet/ContextProviders/SessionProvider.cs).

I've attempted to port it by hand, and failed, so used Telerik's C# to VB converter. It outputs code that looks pretty good, and with only one tweak, the class itself works great. Except the inherits clause.

The code I've got it to now:

```vb
Namespace codeRR.Client.AspNet.CurrentUserContext    
    Public Class CurrentUserContext
        Inherits IContextInfoProvider

        Public Function Collect(ByVal context As IErrorReporterContext) As ContextCollectionDTO
            Dim CurrentUser As CurrentUser = CType(HttpContext.Current.Session("CurrentUser"), CurrentUser)
            If CurrentUser Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
            Dim converter = New ObjectToContextCollectionConverter()
            Dim collection = converter.Convert(Name, CurrentUser)
            Return If(collection.Properties.Count = 0, Nothing, collection)
        End Function

        Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
            Get
                Return "CurrentUser"
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace
```

So very similar to the example code, but returning my custom object instead, basically. The Inherits line fails with:

> Classes can only inherit from other classes.

Which does make sense, since `IContextInfoProvider` is an Interface. 
I'm just stuck on how I actually use it in VB. I need to plug the class into a function that accepts an object of type `IContextInfoProvider`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/implements-statement

Comment: You can reference a c# library in  your VB project. Why don't you just compile Coderr to a dll and add it as a reference?

Comment: In VB.NET you use `Inherits` to inherit from a base-class, and `Implements` to implement an interface.

Comment: This is vb.net code with a C# lisp :)  In vb.net you can't inherit an interface, you can only implement one.  Pretty sensible syntax btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error gives you a good indication of what the problem is. While a Class can inherit from another Class it can't inherit from an Interface.

Inheritance implies deriving some actual implementation of behaviour which a Class contains, as well as its 'signature' whereas an Interface simply defines its 'signature' with an expectation of the implementation of suitable behaviour in the implementing Class, hence it can only be implemented.

So,

```vb
Public Class CurrentUserContext
    Inherits IContextInfoProvider
```

should be

```vb
Public Class CurrentUserContext
    Implements IContextInfoProvider
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct, a bit more text would probably help to clarify things for both the OP and future readers.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, fair comment. Hope my edit has helped. :-).

Comment: Yes, it did help. +1

Comment: Bingo, that did the trick. Thanks heaps. And yes, the extra details helps explain why, that's fantastic.

Answer (score 2):

Classes can inherit from other classes or they can implement interfaces. Interfaces traditionally start with an upper-case `I`, such as `IContextInfoProvider`.

In C#, a class can implement an interface or inherit from another class using the same syntax:

```
// Implement an interface
public class CurrentUserContext : IContextInfoProvider

// Inherit from a class
public class CurrentUserContext : MyContextBaseClass
```

In VB.Net, however, a class that implements an interface or a class that inherits from another class takes on two different syntax's:

```
' Implement an interface
Public Class CurrentUserContext
    Implements IContextInfoProvider

' Inherit from a class
Public Class CurrentUserContext
    Inherits MyContextBaseClass
```

In your case, you should be using `Implements` instead of `Inherits` since you are implementing an interface and not inheriting from a class.

I hope this clears things up!